# Quirk while debugging Javascript app in Webstorm 8

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints, webstorm

I'm trying to debug an AngularJS app in Chrome (with the Jetbrains extension) within Webstorm 8. It's working just fine, but the only naggy thing is that the actual file that has breakpoints in it doesn't get *debugged*, but a readonly copy that reads as the full url of the file is (see screenshot). It works, but I cannot edit the readonly file while moving from line to line.

edit: plus, the IDE usually shows an outdated version of my JS file and I have to manually refresh it to see the correct one.

[image: readonly file]

The Webstorm Run/Debug config for Javascript is really straight forward, basically just the URL to the app.

Does anyone knows how to avoid this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't

The longer answer is, the computer is not running the code that you see on the screen, that's just what the debugger is showing you. The computer is actually running optimized, non-human-readable Javascript bytecode, which is created when you start your JS program, after syntax is checked, namespaces are created and memory is allocated for variables etc. You can't edit that bytecode by writing JS code directly, at least not with any debugger I know of (and I'm fairly certain you can't with Webstorm specifically; I use PHPStorm and its Javascript debugger).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the editing is not the problem. The problem is the new file being opened in the IDE, and that it's usually outdated

Comment: Yeah I found that a bit confusing at first too. Doesn't it close them if you stop the debugger anyway though? If you're editing the code, you probably want to stop the debugger anyway, since you need to restart it to test code changes regardless. Webstorm is simply showing you an accurate representation of the code it is debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Such problems usually mean that remote files are not correctly mapped to local ('remote URL' not correctly set for local files in Run configuration), so the debugger can't map the files being executed to your actual sources. I'm not sure what your application looks like... But, as Angular apps structure is more or less standard, I can suggest mapping the 'app' folder to `'http://localhost:9000'` in javascript debug run configuration you are using to debug your angular code

Comment: I tried mapping http://localhost:9000 to /app at first, and even now that's how it's configured, but I don't see any difference

Comment: then a different mapping is required. I can suggest to either create a support ticket to get help, or try to figure out the correct mappings yourself. Please also make sure that there are no symlinks in your project